# how to handle drop down button with Server Actions -Nextjs

Tags: post, next.js, drop-down-menu, jsx, server-side-rendering

i am just try how to deal with server actions and forms , so i have a form and API to post to it , all input fields works, i got all fields input except the value of the drop down button,
in the dropDown Button the client choose a service by its title then i want to take this chosen service and post it like this :

```
{
    "clientId": "clientId",
    "clientName": "clientName ",
    "clientPhone": "clientPhone",
    "clientStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "chosenServiceId": "5652c359-8400-43f4-bb72-c61dd6a553ed",
    "chosenServiceName": "Sample Service 8",
    "createdAt": "2023-09-13T03:11:31.458Z"
},
```

this is my code  :

```
import { getServices } from "@/app/services/services/services";
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import React, { Suspense,useRef } from 'react';
import ServiceSelect from "./select_Service";


let clientServiceName = '';
async function addClient(data: FormData) {
    'use server';
    // Extract client data from the FormData object
    const clientName = data.get("clientName");
    const clientPhone = data.get("clientPhone");
    const clientEmail = data.get("clientEmail");
    const clientServiceId = data.get("clientService");

    // // Fetch the services to find the selected service by ID
    // const services = await getServices();
    // const selectedService = services.find(
    //     (service: { serviceTitle: string; serviceId: string }) =>
    //         service.serviceId === clientServiceId
    // );

    // if (!selectedService) {
    //     console.error("Selected service not found");
    //     return; 
    // }

    // Create an object with the client data including chosenServiceId and chosenServiceName
    const clientData = {
        clientName,
        clientPhone,
        clientEmail,
        clientServiceId: clientServiceId,
        clientStatus: "IN_PROGRESS",
        chosenServiceName: clientServiceName,
    };

    // Convert the client data to JSON
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(clientData);

    // Define the URL for adding a client (replace with the correct endpoint)
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/clients"; // Replace with the correct endpoint for adding a client

    // Define the token
    const token =
        process.env.TOKEN;

    // Define the request options
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Include the token in the request headers
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: jsonData,
    };

    try {
        // Send the POST request to add the client
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions);

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Request failed with status: " + response.status);
        }

        // If the request was successful, you can handle the response here
        // For example, you can parse the response JSON and perform any necessary actions
        const responseData = await response.json();
        console.log("Client added successfully:", responseData);

        // Optionally, you can revalidate tags or perform a redirect here
        // revalidateTag("posts");
        // redirect("/");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding client:", error);
        // Handle the error here
    }
}

export const BookingForm = ({ action, services }: { action: string; services: { serviceTitle: string }[] }) => {
    return (
        <div className="main-contact-area pb-120">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="section-title">
                    <span>Contact Us</span>
                    <h2>Drop us a message for any query</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                        quibusdam deleniti porro praesentium. Aliquam minus quisquam velit
                        in at nam.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div className="row align-items-center">
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        <div className="contact-wrap contact-pages mb-0">
                            <div className="contact-form">
                                <form action={addClient}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="clientName"
                                                    placeholder="Name"
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                    id="clientName"
                                                    // value={contact.name}
                                                    // onChange={handleChange}
                                                    required
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="clientEmail"
                                                    placeholder="Email"
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                    id="clientEmail"
                                                    // value={contact.email}
                                                    // onChange={handleChange}
                                                    required
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="clientPhone"
                                                    placeholder="Phone number"
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                    id="clientPhone"
                                                    // value={contact.number}
                                                    // onChange={handleChange}
                                                    required
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">

                                            <div className="col-12">
      <select
        className="form-select bg-light border-0"
        name="clientService"
        style={{ height: "55px", color: "black" }}
    
      >
        <option value="">Select A Service</option>
        {services && services.length === 0 ? (
          <option value="" disabled>
            Loading...
          </option>
        ) : (
          services.map((service, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={service.serviceTitle}>
              {service.serviceTitle}
            </option>
          ))
        )}
        {!services && (
          <option value="" disabled>
            Loading...
          </option>
        )}
      </select>
    </div>
  
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <button
                                                type="submit"
                                                className="default-btn btn-two"
                                            >
                                                Book
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        <div className="contact-img">
                            <img src="/images/contact-img.png" alt="Image" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

so how to do this and can i do this only with server side (server action)?

Regards